# How to give onPress function for BottomNavigationBar menu in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a bottomnavigation bar in flutter  ,what i want is on click of the individual widgets of the bottombar it should navigate me to the next page

```
    Widget _bottemTab() {
    return new BottomNavigationBar(


    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    onTap:(newIndex) => setState((){_currentIndex = newIndex;}),
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: [
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/home.png",
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Home',
          ),
      ),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/shopping-bagg.png",
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Mall',
          )),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/qr-code.png",
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Scan',
          )),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(

          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/bank.png",
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Bank',
          )),



      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/delivery.png",
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Inbox',
          )),


    ]);
      }
```

i want is on click of the individual widgets of the bottombar it should navigate me to the next page which i have created separately for each menu items of bottom navigation view..any help is appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `build()` method, you can add this logic.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget widget = Container(); // default
  switch (_currentIndex) {
    case 0:
      widget = FirstPage();
      break;

    case 1:
      widget = SecondPage();
      break;

    case 2:
      widget = ThirdPage();
      break;
  }

  return Scaffold(
    body: widget,
    // ...
  );
}
```

---

**Update:**

I'm not sure how you did that, here you can see a small example of doing it right way.

[image]

```
int _index = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget child = Container();

  switch(_index) {
    case 0:
      child = FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.orange);
      break;

    case 1:
      child = FlutterLogo();
      break;
  }

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
    body: SizedBox.expand(child: child),
  );
}

Widget _bottomTab() {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: _index,
    onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one), title: Text("1")),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two), title: Text("2")),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps.

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;
static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
static const _pages = <Widget>[
  Home(),//this is a stateful widget on a separate file 
  Business(),//this is a stateful widget on a separate file 
  School(),//this is a stateful widget on a separate file 

];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Cannot use static const to create the _pages arrays. it will throw an error saying  "The values in a const list literal must be constants". Can use var _pages =  <Widget>[Home(),Business(), School() ];